# Xubuntu 17.04 panel shows utc not local time

Tags: xubuntu, timezone

Since upgrading to Xubuntu 17.04 from 16.10 the clock on the panel at the top of the screen shows UTC when I am logged in. On the login screen it shows BST (UTC+1). I have tried changing the timezone but the logged in panel shows utc whilst login screen shows the time from the new timezone.

I have also tried setting the TZ environment variable in ~/.profile to no effect.

Help

Comment: additionally sudo hwclock shows BST

Comment: What about the settings of the panel clock?

Comment: Europe/London. an the timezone is the only available setting - there is no DST/BST type setting available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, you must keep the timezone field in blank or write the exact time zone name.

Any other word will turn the clock to the UTC time.  For example, if you put "New York" as the time zone, then the clock will show UTC time because it is not a standard time zone name. So instead you must put "America/New_York".

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!! Blank the timezone field in the panel clock properties and it displays the right time! Anything else (I tried Athens as well as London) seems to get UTC